# Custom Signout page in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I'm trying to create a custom signout page, or force a redirect to the login page...really anything other than the default signout.aspx page would be good. There is lots of info out there explaining how to use powershell to set a custom signout page, unfortunately this isn't possible in o365. Has anyone had any experience with overwriting the default signout behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go to Microsoft Azure behind your O365 tenant and customize the branding of login page to some extent.

P.S.  *Company branding is a feature that is only available when you enable Azure Active Directory Premium.*

Source and Further information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn532270.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Currently there is no feature in SharePoint Online for custom Sign out page.

Comment: This post is about the signout.aspx and not the Access Denied page